# responsive_sizer version 3.2.0 Error: Undefined name 'View'

Tags: flutter

Error from console

```
../../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/responsive_sizer-3.2.0/lib/src/helper.dart:57:18: Error: Undefined name 'View'.
    pixelRatio = View.of(context).devicePixelRatio;
                 ^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception
```

- I use flutter version 3.7.5

It happens this morning when I run on both Android and iOS. Is it a bug from the Library?

Comment: looks like it.. try downgrading/ upgrading version  one by one.

Answer (score 0):

change View to MediaQuery.of(context) this fix my issue